# Peskun's ordering after raising to a power

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two Markov transition kernel (or matrix) with the same stationary distribution $\pi$, furthermore assume they are all positive （an operator is positive if the spectrum are all non-negative. Suppose $P\succ Q$ in the sense that $P(x,y) \geq Q(x,y)$ for any $x\neq y$. I am wondering if $P^2 \succ Q^2$?

Tthe result is obviously not true without the positive assumption. Consider 
$P =\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $
Q = \begin{pmatrix}
0.5&0.5\\
0.5&0.5\\
\end{pmatrix}$
gives us a counterexample.

Comment: It probably is not true, because probabilities are positive numbers between zero and one, and multiplying such numbers yields smaller numbers, not larger ones.